# Obtener información de dos tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Trabajo con SQL Server 2014 tengo la necesidad de obtener datos de dos tablas para eso puedo hacer un `INNER JOIN` el detalle es que cuando hago esta consulta.

[image: consulta sql]

Necesito utilizar `EspecificacionId` para poder hacer otro `INNER JOIN` en mi tabla Opciones.

Pero el tema es que debo tomar los valores que tenga en `EspecificacionId` en esa consulta tiene dos Especificaciones la toma es dinamicamente eso quiero decir que debo utilizar en este caso las dos pero recorriendo y tomando los valores para luego ir a buscar a la tabla Opciones. **¿Como lo puedo hacer?**.

Mi idea sería recorrer el resultado de la consulta devuelta mediante un foreach o for y tomar los datos de EspesificacionId para guardarlo en un array y con esos resultados hacer el `INNER JOIN` en la tabla Opciones todo eso en SQL Server.

[image: Especificaciones]

Saludos!

Comment: Puedes compartir la estructura de la tabla Opciones? Saludos.

Comment: @Rostan Listo!!

Comment: Todo los campos que lleva id son numéricos.

Comment: Podrías considerar el uso de una `view` o vista y de ahí realizar tu consulta a esa vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como lo veo lo que necesitas es llegar a la tercera tabla [Opciones] haciendo un match de las 2 primeras tablas, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT*
FROM EspecificacionProductos AS EP
INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E
    ON (EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId)
INNER JOIN Opciones AS O
    ON (EP.EspecificacionId = O.EspecificacionId)
WHERE EP.ProductId = 7
```

Con ello llegas a la tabla extendida de Opciones, y podrías tener las columnas que necesitas.